# Where to place Javascript used in one page only in Rails 7 with importmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

When using Rails 7 with import maps, where do I put code that should be executed by one view only?

Specifically, I have a view that needs to run some Javascript code on load.  My Javascript looks something like this:

```
import {TheController} from "./TheController"

let controller = new TheController();

document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    controller.onLoad();
  }
};
```

How do I setup the Javascript environment so that the `document.onreadystatechange` code is executed only by the desired view?  (Everything *almost* works when I put this code in a file imported by `application.js`, but then it gets executed by *every* view.)

I suspect the answer is to create separate importmaps and importmap_tags; but, I can find any demonstrations of how to do that in Rails 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @Azrklm points out, the answer is contained in this video https://youtu.be/PtxZvFnL2i0?t=1287 beginning at time 21:38.

Suppose we have some JavaScript that we want to run only on a view called `FancyView`. Here are the steps

1. Place the code unique to `FancyView` in its own file, say `FancyView.js` (and remove it from `application.js`, if necessary).
2. Add a line for `FancyView.js` to the importmap:  `pin "FancyView"`
3. Add the line `<%= yield :head %> to` application.html.erb`.  (This tells Rails that individual views/layouts may want to add additional information to the web page's head.)

   ```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
   <%= javascript_importmap_tags %> <%# This loads application.js %>
   <%= yield :head %>
   ```
4. Add a `javascript_import_module_tag` to the view:

   ```
   <% content_for :head do %>
     <%= javascript_import_module_tag "FancyView" %>
   <% end %>
   ```

Comment: Can anybody tell why the code following step 4 isn't formatted?  I highlighted it and clicked the {} button in the editor (several times).  It also appears to be indented 4 spaces.

Comment: Not sure why this happened in the first place, but it seemed like the code in step 4 was indented one space to little to be interpreted as a code block. Fixed it for you!

Comment: But the javascript code is executed only once.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: If the page is using a Stimulus Controller you could also just import FancyView when that controller loads....correct?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone has a similar problem finds this question, I found the answer from @Zack to be perfectly concise and exactly what I needed, BUT with 2 important caveats:

1. I couldn't use the capcase naming convention for my js. `FancyView` needed to be `fancyView`.
2. The javascript_import_module_tag should come after your javascript_importmap_tags

   ```
   <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
   <%= yield(:head) %>
   ```

This is also now explained on the rails github page: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#selectively-importing-modules

Thanks @Zack!

Answer (score 0):

DHH explains it pretty well have a look plz
https://youtu.be/PtxZvFnL2i0?t=1287

Comment: To make this more useful (and receive more upvotes) you probably want to include the actual solution in your answer as well.

Comment: I myself exploring from last 2 days, How can I bring a simple bootstrap theme into rails 7 and can't figure out where to put the CSS and JS
Although, a find a small guide which may help others in accordance with their problem.
Kindly have a look at the following link:

https://kmitov.com/posts/rails-7-with-bootstrap-5-by-cssbundling-rails-with-dart-sass-and-jsbundling-rails-with-esbuild-no-webpack-and-webpacker-and-a-salt-of-stimulus/